# Monero wallet says sent 25 XMR, other wallet says 0 received!

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I transferred some monero from one GUI wallet to another one and while transaction shows up in both wallets the sending wallet sent 25 XMR (and shows that) the receiving wallet says 0 XMR received (with the same transaction ID).

How do I sort this out?

Update to add important infor:

GUI version v0.14.0.0 (Qt 5.7.0)
Embedded Monero version: v0.14.0.2 
Downloaded this morning

If it is important the receiving wallet was a ledger backed one.

Comment: Which version of the GUI wallet are you using?

Comment: GUI version v0.14.0.0 (Qt 5.7.0) 
Embedded Monero version: v0.14.0.2
Downloaded this morning.

Comment: And which version of the Ledger Monero app and Ledger Live firmware are you using?

Comment: Also commented here by the way -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/aw86rx/updated_information_thread_regarding_the/ei9hj01/?context=3

Answer (score -2):

My guess would be due to the recent hard fork and verification times being slowed down. I'm running a full  node and things look weird at the moment. The data is on the blockchain and should eventually sync. It doens't look like the Ledger bug is affecting you.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/aywyj2/is_monero_safe_to_use_again/

Comment: If the transaction is received and verified, this hard fork or slow verification times should have no impact on the amount received. A bug somewhere is more likely.